# C# Brackets between string constructor and the string itself

Tags: c#, string, brackets

I was reading through some of the MSDN documentation in C# and found a piece of code i can use had these brackets between the string constructor and the string itself like this

```
string[] stringname;
```

What does this mean, or what does it do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's just an array declaration.  That means `stringname` holds an array of strings (or rather, it *declares* an array-of-strings variable, since it doesn't actually hold anything yet).

There are a few variations in C# for declaring arrays and initializing.  There's a good rundown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

```
var arr1 = new string[5];                  // empty array of length 5
string[] arr2 = { "a", "b", "c" };         // pre-populated array with 3 items
```

Comment: +1 just throwing one more to the pot - var name = new[] { "a", "b", "c" }; lol.

Answer (score 1):

It's an array declaration. When you declare an array, you don't specify the size, like this:

```
string[] stringname;
```

To actually initialize it, you have to either specify the size or pre-initialize it with actual data.

```
string[] stringname = new string[3]; // would allocate an array for 3 strings, but without setting any value on it.
string[] stringname = new [] { "andré", "joseph" }; // would allocate the 2 strings in the array, with values on it.
```

To understand more about arrays, please refer to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This defines an array of strings

Answer (score 0):

This is declaring an Array of Strings.  If you want to read more on Arrays in C# I would recommend...

[Info on Arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

"**Arrays in General**

C# arrays are zero indexed; that is, the array indexes start at zero. Arrays in C# work similarly to how arrays work in most other popular languages There are, however, a few differences that you should be aware of.
When declaring an array, the square brackets ([]) must come after the type, not the identifier. Placing the brackets after the identifier is not legal syntax in C#."---MSDN Link

Any book on C# should have more information on the Array subject.